# connect owncloud to ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one, owncloud-server

Is it possible to connect ownCloud to ubuntu one over the "External storage support" app in ownCloud. It works pretty well with dropbox and Google Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unfortunately it is not. As you probably have seen, Ubuntu One is not listed in supported protocols in the external-storage dropdown menu in your Owncloud environment.

In fact, the protocol that is used for U1 is not a standard protocol (but Google Drive and Dropbox are not standard either). It is developed by Canonical. It is called ubuntuone-storageprotocol. API's to interface with Ubuntu One are however available so there is nothing stopping the owncloud devs to start supporting this. It just hasn't happened (yet).

Comment: I don't know what you think makes what dropbox or Google Drive do, be "standard" protocols. They are completely non-standard protocols.

Comment: Forgive me @dobey but where exactly did you see me write that they did :) ?

Comment: what I was just trying to emphazise was that you can't connect from Owncloud to U1 storage using standard protocols like webdav, ftp and such.

Comment: your answer implies they are standard, and the U1 protocol is not. You do not say that owncloud is using DAV or FTP to talk to dropbox or Google Drive, and AFAIK, you can't use those to talk to either one.

Comment: Sorry still not reading it like that myself, but no worries! I will edit the answer to make it totaly unambiguous